# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create and write a file in a docker container. The python script works fine in my local machine but I don't know how to make it work in docker. I created the app.py and the dockerfile with the official docker documentation.

Then I created a volume with **docker volume create my-vol**.
The hello world method works fine.
This are the files:

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - my-vol
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

App.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api/hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, Docker!'
    

@app.route('/api/ask')
def ask():
    try:
        my_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt","r")
        print(my_file.read())
        newString=input("Ingresa un nuevo string")
        new_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8")
        new_file.write(newString)
        new_file.close()
        my_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt","r")
        print(my_file.read())
    except IOError:
        new_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8")
        new_file.write("Archivo creado exitosamente \n")
        new_file.close()
        my_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt","r")
        print(my_file.read())
    finally:
        print("exit")
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 12, in ask
    my_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my-vol/newfile.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/app/app.py", line 21, in ask
    new_file=open("/my-vol/newfile.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my-vol/newfile.txt'
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2021 10:59:32] "GET /api/ask HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Please, include th whole traceback

Comment: Where did you create the file you're attempting to open?

Comment: @BMitch in this line new_file=open("newfile.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8") it creates one

Comment: The volume mount `my-vol` very likely isn't doing what you want it to do. I'm honestly not sure what that is expected to do, maybe compose turns it into a relative container path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is missing `/my-vol` folder. It throws inside of exception handler and in the `except` block again. You comment that it fails in opening it for reading but it fails in attempting to write it in fact.

Check if the folder does exist first and create it if it does not.

Sidenote: Putting such code inside the exception handler is really a bad practice. You usually just set some flag inside your `except` block and care about the problem outside the try..except block.

Also putting so much code inside single try block is also bad practice, you just put the least amount of code possible there.